# PopupWindow shown at wrong place in onGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a `View` say *anchor* and a `PopupWindow` *pop*. *pop* is shown with [`showAsDropDown`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View)) when I click a button on anchor.

What I want is to show *pop* automatically at the first time *anchor* comes to screen. So I override `onAttachedToWindow` and add a `onGlobalLayoutListener` and show *pop* in it. see below:

```
private boolean mFirstRun = true;
    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if(mFirstRun) {
            mFirstRun = false;
            getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    showPopup();
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The result is, only the first time (see above) *pop* will stay **right above** *anchor*. I have confirmed the width and height of *pop* is correct. when the button click triggers, *pop* is shown at the proper place.

After spending some time I found the problem is in `onGlobalLayoutListener` *anchor*.`getLocationOnScreen` has a larger value than the final value so there's no enough space for *pop* below it.

How can I fix this? and why the screen location is incorrect in that listener?

Comment: What about onPreDrawListener? Supposedly there all the values are in their final form.

Comment: have tried that, but the same result. And my log output like this: measure, layout, draw  measure layout draw , two times